# I want to create an in-house system. About GCE Firewall

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I want to create an in-house system with GCE. I want to make HTTP and SSH connections only for people in the company, but not others. What should I do with a firewall?

Comment: Please edit your question with details. How do you define "people in the company"? Are they using the same IP CIDR block, have the same domain identity (*.example.com), etc? Are you using G Suite? Is your project under a GCP Organization? How are you managing SSH keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, a Google Cloud project you create in Google Cloud Platform comes with the default firewall rules:

- default-allow-icmp – allow from any source to all the network IP. ICMP protocol is mostly used to ping the target.
- default-allow-internal – allow connectivity between instances on any port.
- default-allow-rdp – allow RDP session to connect to Windows servers from any source.
- default-allow-ssh – enable SSH session to connect to UNIX servers from any source.

You can [create firewall rules](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls#creating_firewall_rules) in combination with [network tags](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/add-remove-network-tags) so the VM instances with this associated tag will be the target of your firewall rule. Moreover, you can combine multiple ports in a single rule.

Here below there is an example to allow HTTP and SSH connections via gcloud command in the Cloud Shell (alternatively, you can use the GCP graphical interface):

gcloud compute firewall-rules create allow-ssh-and-http --network default --allow tcp:22,80 --direction ingress --priority 1000 --target-tags ssh-and-http --source-ranges [CIDR_RANGE]

Afterwards, you have to add the network tag to the specific GCE instance.

gcloud compute instances add-tags [INSTANCE-NAME] --zone [ZONE] --tags ssh-and-http

If you wish to have  a more granular access control, you have to set the proper permissions for each user or service account via [IAM & Admin](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/overview).